# i can't set -Xmx in java

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, jvm

I use spring-boot 2. If i do :

> export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx756m

Then:

> java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE
>   'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'

```
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 16777216                            {product}
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 792723456                           {product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
```

But if i reload console. MaxHeapSize is reset .

And it changes nothing :

```
java -XshowSettings:all
VM settings:
Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 237.81M
Ergonomics Machine Class: client
Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

if i do :

```
 nohup java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Xmx660m -jar /home/ec2-user/project.jar >test.out 2>&1 &
```

in text.out:

```
nohup: ignoring input
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size: 660.00M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

But if I enter manually  `java -XshowSettings:all` Nothing changes:

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 237.81M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

and:

```
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 257949696                           {product}
```

Total memory:1gb

Comment: "But if i reload console. MaxHeapSize is reset ." Is that environment variable still set when you "reload console"? You may have to set it in some startup or profile file.

Comment: @Thilo I have to do export _JAVA_OPTIONS before start jar or after?

Comment: It has to be set when you start your Java program. You cannot change these settings for a JVM that is already running.

Answer (score 1):

> But if i reload console. MaxHeapSize is reset .

This is not how JVM works. In order to get your memory related changes to take place one has to restart java programme.
**It is not possible to apply jvm settings on the fly**

Comment: IF I first do  export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx756m then i start jar. Same problem